# How do you type the '§' symbol (section sign) in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

At the moment I'm copying and pasting it but you cant copy and paste in Minecraft. How can I type it on a QWERTY keyboard?

Comment: What kind of QWERTY keyboard? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY as you can see there are many many types...

Answer (score 16):

It looks likes you have two options:

There is an [<kbd>ALT</kbd> Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) you can try to type.  To try it:

- Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key on your keyboard
- Using the number pad (it must be the number pad), type <kbd>2</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd> (21).  Make sure Num Lock is on.
- Release <kbd>ALT</kbd> and it should type a §

On Mac, it looks like if you hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and type <kbd>6</kbd>, it will type the § sign (<kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>5</kbd> for extended U.S. keyboards).

The other way is to use plugins that replace the § with something else.  Looking around, it seems [CommandBook for Bukkit](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/commandbook) may work.

Sources: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes#Typing), [Talk:Formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Formatting_codes#How_do_you_get_.C2.A7_sign.3F)

Comment: As for the Mac, then it really depends on the localization of keyboard. My alt+6 gives a ™ where shift+$ gives a § ... A solution to this could be to use the Keyboard Viewer to see which combination would give a §

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen what does alt + 5 give you?

Comment: It gives me a ∞ ... I'm on a danish mac keyboard without a keypad; https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22DK/A/magic-keyboard-danish

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen oh boy, that's much different.  Not sure what it would be for a Danish Mac Keyboard with no number pad... I would say just keep experimenting.

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen I also noticed that on that keyboard, next to the 1 on the number line is the § symbol along with the $ sign.

Comment: You can change the input source for Mac keyboards - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18448?locale=en_US Notably, `§` is the key next to enter/return when using the Czech input source

Comment: NB: On Linux desktops you can use CTRL-SHIFT-U followed by A7<space> to get §

Comment: Esben's results for Alt+5 are consistent with the US Mac Extended layout that I remember.  Also what my xkb Macintosh layout gives me, and it says:  `// symbols definition for a Macintosh "Extended" keyboard`.

Comment: Alt+0+1+6+7 also works.

Answer (score 7):

Minecraft stopped the Alt code insertion a long time ago. At one point they allowed insertion of Unicode characters in command blocks, but that too was removed. The only way now is via external editors, such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac).

Other than external editors or Bukkit plugins(Essentials v3 supports using & instead), I do not think there is any other way to insert section symbols.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press 0167. If that doesn't work, try 21.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft prevents typing "§" characters into in-game text fields. In modern versions pasted text will automatically be filtered. Sending chat messages in servers with this symbol will usually get you kicked, even on vanilla.

There are 4 ways you can bypass this restriction:

- Client-side modifications (remove text field restrictions).
- Server-side plugins and modifications (which for example replace "&" with "§", or prevents players being kicked).
- Server console ("§" can be used in commands).
- External editors (for example, [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/releases/tag/v2.8.0-win)).

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can copy-paste the symbol into mc, it doesn't show up but then if you type a number or letter for your formatting (e.g. paste and then 1) the no./letter won't show up, and then anything you type after it will show up in the formatting.