# Typing the section sign (§) in modern versions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen posts asking about this issue, that it's been restricted to type ALT characters (such as §, or ALT 21) into Minecraft from a certain version, but I keep seeing answers like "you can only fix this by changing client changes" or "only possible in NBTExplorer". How exactly could I do this?

I'm also trying this in a multiplayer server, to color item names in anvils, I think it was possible at some point without commands, but I don't remember. So if this isn't possible without permissions or other players won't see the color of the item name and it's only local in the first place then I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310050/163757

Answer (score -1):

Please don't down vote this, this is simply an alternative to the section sign.

In singleplayer, you can use commands to give yourself coloured items:

```
/give @s minecraft:dirt{display:{Name:'{"text":"Coloured","color":"red","italic":false,"extra":[{"text":" Text","color": "blue"}]}'}}
```

How it works:

```
// Give an item.
give
// To the executing entity.
@s
// Give dirt.
minecraft:dirt
// With NBT Tag.
{
    // With name.
    display: {
        name: '         
            {
                // With text "Coloured".
                "text": "Coloured",
                // Coloured red.
                "color": "red",
                // Remove italic effect.
                "italic": false,
                // Add extra text components.
                "extra": [
                    // Add the string " Text" coloured blue.
                    {"text": " Text","color":"blue"}

                ]

            }
        '   
    }

}
```

There is a mod to do this on 1.17 on multiplayer: [ColorUtility](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/colorutility).

Unfortunately, most servers (including vanilla) will kick you if you use it in chat (it's actually a reliable way to get put in limbo on Hypixel), but they probably won't in an anvil.