# How Do i Get Cursed Text in Minecraft Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I Tried Getting `"Cursed Text"` In Minecraft Java So I Copied `"§k"` And Put It In Chat
And It Only Said `"k"` I'm So ****:(****Sad****):****

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you type the '§' symbol (section sign) in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310050/how-do-you-type-the-symbol-section-sign-in-minecraft)

Comment: I'd say it's not a duplicate, as you can achieve obfuscated text, which seems to be OPs actual goal, through other means. Just because their solution attempt is flawed, doesn't mean that a somewhat related question answers theirs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "obfuscated" text, not "cursed".

And while Java Edition still supports using the `§` symbol internally, the proper way of doing this is using the [raw JSON text format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format). They even try to prevent you from typing it in-game through the client.

Now, depending on where you're trying to get this text the command you use will need to be different, and you can use a generator like https://minecraftjson.com to create more difficult commands or to help you learn how to use it.

Here is an example for obfuscated text in the chat:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"This is some cursed text","obfuscated":true}
```

Here is a slightly larger example

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"This is some ","color":"red"},{"text":"cursed","obfuscated":true,"color":"dark_red","bold":true},{"text":" text"}]
```